# Select wont work

Tags: sql, syntax, syntax-error

Just what the dickens is wrong with this query?

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(CASE myDate
             WHEN DATEDIFF(day, myDate, GETDATE()) = 0 THEN [Items]
             ELSE 0
           END)
FROM   myTable
GROUP  BY id
```

???

Error Says

```
"Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

Comment: `CASE myDate` should just be `CASE`

Comment: You're mixing up the syntax between a Simple Case expression and a Searched Case expression - they're two different beasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query you want:

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, myDate, GETDATE()) = 0 THEN [Items] ELSE 0 END)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id;
```

The `myDate` after the `case` was doing nothing for you.  It is allowed syntactically for the alternative form of the `case` statement:

```
sum(case mydate when '2013-01-01' then 'New Years Day' . . .
```

But not when you have an expression after the `when`.

Answer (score 0):

`SUM(CASE myDate WHEN DATEDIFF(day, myDate, GETDATE()) )` you have missed a closed bracket I guess

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `mydate` after the `CASE`

```
SELECT  id, 
        SUM(CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(day, myDate, GETDATE()) = 0 
            THEN [Items] ELSE 0 END) 

FROM myTable GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id,
       SUM(CASE myDate
             WHEN DATEDIFF(day, myDate, GETDATE() = 0) THEN [Items]
             ELSE 0
           END)
FROM   myTable
GROUP  BY id

this is correct